# Python-Requests: direct .pem pinning with self-signed cert

Tags: python, ssl

Using python-requests, how can I pin a self-signed .pem certificate for a specific server directly, without using CA root bundles?

Is this currently possible? If yes, can you please provide an example?

I read https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.8.1/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification but am not sure if this applies to what I'm trying to do:

> You can also specify a local cert to use as client side certificate, as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both file’s path: `requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/server.crt', '/path/key')) Response [200]`

Answer (score 8):

Because the certificate file is self-signed, this works just as you would do it normally with requests. Below is a step-by-step procedure:

1. Obtain the self-signed certificate, ideally in some secure, out-of-band manner. For example, I run a webserver that offers HTTPS access via a self-signed certificate, so I downloaded the certificate using `scp`:

   ```
   scp <username>@<server>:/path/to/certfile.crt .
   ```
2. Because I use nginx this is already in PEM format, but if it's not you'll need to convert it. That's outside the scope of this answer.
3. Use the certificate file from inside requests:

   ```
   r = requests.get('https://yoursite.com/', verify='certfile.crt')
   ```

That's all you need to do.

If you can't obtain the certificate in an out-of-band manner you trust, you can obtain the certificate using your browser. All browsers will let you export the certificate via their UIs. This is less-secure: if someone is going to MITM you then they may well have already started, and can offer you their MITM root CA instead of your self-signed cert.

Comment: Does this always verify the whole certificate or is it possible to limit it to checking the public key in the cert?

Answer (score 2):

You can also verify certificates against their fingerprints.
For this you need a custom transport adapter for requests.
An example for a simple one can be found here:

[https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer/blob/9d3a9611b2db2e92f933df30dd98c341a50c6211/vdirsyncer/utils/**init**.py#L198](https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer/blob/9d3a9611b2db2e92f933df30dd98c341a50c6211/vdirsyncer/utils/__init__.py#L198)

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

class _FingerprintAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, fingerprint=None, **kwargs):
        self.fingerprint = str(fingerprint)
        super(_FingerprintAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       assert_fingerprint=self.fingerprint)
```

Comment: requests-toolbelt now contains this implementation: https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/adapters.html#fingerprintadapter